# How can I go about designing this border?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

It's thicker in the middle and gets thinner on the left and right.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do for those is make a short horizontal line as thick as you want in the center of your document, rasterize it, then use motion blur on it with a horizontal angle as long as you need it to be.

Make a line whatever thickness you want

[image: Make a line whatever thickness you want]

Convert to Smart Object

[image]

Go to filter > blur > motion blur

[image: Go to filter > blur > motion blur]

Make the angle set to 0 and add as much blur as you need to make the effect work

[image: Make the angle set to 0 and add as much blur as you need to make the effect work]

It's not necessarily thinner at the sides, but the fadeout makes it look this way.

Comment: If you're going to use this method then you should at least use Smart Filter for the Blur

Comment: @Ryan, Sorry, was in a rush.  I've changed the second step to show the line turning into a smart object to then use the blur.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to create the line in Illustrator first then import into photoshop to finish.

1. Create a line and add a 1pt stroke
2. Using the width tool - expand the centre of the line to your desired width.
3. Copy, paste in to photoshop
4. Gaussian blur to desired effect
5. Create layer mask and erase edges for added bleed.

Comment: This is really convoluted method. I have no idea why you need to use Illustrator.